# Success page get customer name and order id

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to echo the customer name and order id on the checkout success page.

I currently use this line to display the customer name:

```
<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId()); echo $order->getCustomerName(); ?>
```

But that echo the value "Guest guest".

And to load the order ID I use this, but that does also not work:

```
<p><?php echo $this->__('Your order ID is <strong> %s.</strong>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())) ?> </p>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: are you doing at success.phtml

Comment: @AmitBera Yes I do it on success.phtml

Comment: is ($this->getOrderId() given order increment id?

Comment: Did you find the solution? Do you need more info?

Answer (score 8):

To get the order details on the checkout success page, use this

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
```

and then retrieve the customer info from the order object like this

```
//If they have no customer id, they're a guest.
if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
    echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
} else {
    //else, they're a normal registered user.
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    echo $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
}
```

Comment: Strange.Its working for me. are u checking for guest customer.?

Comment: Thanks it is working! But how do I echo the order id?

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();` this will print the order id

Comment: please accept and upvote if it helped

Comment: I tried to get the order ID, but when I past that line, it does not echo the order id.

Comment: did u add the `echo` keyword.?

Comment: Yes, but then I get an number, that is not the # order number

Comment: `$orderid = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
    $Incrementid = $order->getIncrementId();`

Comment: that is the order_id, if you want the order increment id, write the code in above comment

Comment: Why can I just use <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId()) ?>?

Comment: yes u can use that too

Comment: But does that line work for guest and for account checkouts?

Comment: yes it will work for guest customers as well

Comment: I tried you code to load the customer name, but than I get this error: Call to a member function getFirstname() on a non-object in /template/checkout/success.phtml on line 113. But that error is only displayed when I use a payment method, that is payed outside our magneto store and redirects after is is completed.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getName();?>
```

This will echo Customer's Name from Billing Info section.

If you want to get Customer name from register customer rather than billing address then try this:

```
<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());
if($order->getCustomerIsGuest()){ //if order created as guest
   echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
}
else //if order created by registered user
   echo $order->getCustomerName();
}
?>
```

This should give you desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If give order increment id then you can customer name.

Whenever a `customer is placed an order as guest` that time customer name is take from `billing address`.

**Try below code:**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
if($order->getId()):
    if($order->getCustomerIsGuest()):
    $name=$order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    else:
    $name=$order->getCustomerName();
    endif;
    echo $name;
endif;
```

Comment: I tried you code to load the customer name, but that only works for payment money check. Because that is place the order directly. When I use a payment method that is payed outside our magento store and redirects when it is complete, it does not display the name.

Comment: is $this->getOrderId() given order increment id?

Comment: No it does not given me the order increment id

Comment: that issue is here....whenever you have place order using other payment gateway except   money check. Bascially magento is carry order id by checkout session variable Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();. may be it not set..

Comment: Do you know how to check and fix this?

Comment: you need to check each payment module return  page..

Answer (score 1):

Here i find out the guest user after placing an order/ from an order increment id. and identified as guest. this is i have done in success.phtml page.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());

    $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$order->getCustomerId())
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->getFirstItem();
if($customer->getConfirmation()!=""){
  echo "Guest Checkout";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code

```
echo $order->getCustomerName();
```

to

```
 echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
```

Comment: Exactly the same has already been suggested in another answer, alongside with an explanation. Please only answer if you can add additional value