# how can I get the customer details from order from the magento database?

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order, query

I want to list the details of all the customer which has made an order.
The customers who has created account , can easily be found out from the admin side.
But how can I find the list of **all the guest customer** who had made orders **from the beginning** of the store.

Please suggest me some **query** so that I can list all the customer from the order table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

$guestOrders = array();
foreach($orders as $order){
   if($order->getCustomerIsGuest()){
      $guestOrders[] = $order;
   }
}

//print all guest orders
foreach($guestOrders as $order){
   echo "<pre>".$order->getId()."</pre>";
}

//print all customer who made guest checkout
foreach($guestOrders as $order){
   echo "<pre>".$order->getCustomerFirstname() ." ".$order->getCustomerLastname()." - ".$order->getCustomerEmail()."</pre>";
   //...........
   //there are lot of other customer attributes you can print.
}
```

**Remember guest orders are not associated with any customer.**

Hope this helps.

**Update [1]**

Even better way:

```
//get only guest orders
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_is_guest', 1); 

//print all customer who made guest checkout
foreach($orders as $order){
   echo "<pre>".$order->getCustomerFirstname() ." ".$order->getCustomerLastname()." - ".$order->getCustomerEmail()."</pre>";
   //...........
   //there are lot of other customer attributes you can print.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For guest , magento have it customer_id as null.So you need to sales model by guest email address and magento set a flagcustomer_is_guest =1whenever customer will checkout as guest.

Magento also save Customer email address to sales model table whenever loggin customers are checkout ,so on this case customer_is_guest =1 is importand

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_is_guest',1) ;
foreach( $orderCollection  as $eachorder){
//var_dump($eachOrder) or print_r($eachOrder);


// you can also use your logic here.

}
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Well it's pretty simple, for guest orders, you can get customer's firstname & lastname as below:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                                            ->getCollection()
                                            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                                            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_is_guest', 1);

foreach($orderCollection as $order):
echo $order->getCustomerFirstname()." ";
echo $order->getCustomerLastname();
endforeach;
```

Check some of below links for better understanding.

[Success page get customer name and order id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72090/success-page-get-customer-name-and-order-id)

https://blog.digiswaps.com/magento-get-customer-details-from-order/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075464/magento-questions-get-customer-details-and-onepage-checkout-success-doesnt-send

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698781/how-do-i-get-customername-from-an-order

**Hope this may help you.**

Comment: @Kishore Patra Was this answer helpful ?

Comment: This is used for retrieving the information of a single customer related to a  particular order, I guess. But I want the list of all the guest customer who had made orders from the beginning of the store.

Comment: Updated my answer, check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get customer detail from order:

```
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    foreach($orders as $order){
        //You can get all data of order easily by echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getdata());
        if($order->getCustomerId())
        {
            $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId()); //customer info loaded
        } 
        else
        {
            //Its guest customer . Do whatever you want                
        }

    }
```