# checkout success page - Can't get order id & customer id

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, guest-checkout

I want to get customer id & order id at order success page.

Already tried this : [Success page get customer name and order id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72090/success-page-get-customer-name-and-order-id) ..But not working

**In index controller**

```
public function successAction()
    {
        $this->_getState()->setCompleteStep(
                Xx_Multistepcheckout_Model_Type_State::STEP_OVERVIEW
            );
        $this->_getState()->setActiveStep(
            Xx_Multistepcheckout_Model_Type_State::STEP_SUCCESS
            );

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        $ids = $this->_getCheckout()->getOrderIds();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => $ids));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

**In order success page**

```
$_orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();
```

But it's not giving any order Id's.

So to get order details I've tried following code in order success page.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
print_r($order->getData());
```

It's also giving me an empty array.

Can you please suggest me what should I can do to get order id and customer id in order success page.

Comment: kaushal which version of magento you have

Comment: Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Comment: are  you added code in your theme ? and also if possible check with template path hint from where that is load

Comment: It's a custom created checkout, Let me know if wish to see any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways I've sorted this..

I was using `$_orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();` multiple times in a success.phtml so second time it was giving me `null` value.

So I've just called `$this->getOrderIds();` only once in success.phtml file.

Answer (score 2):

First:

Check if this exist in your code: https://github.com/Mediotype/Magento-1.7.0.2-Community-Edition/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Success.php

This block show on Success page last order. Then use:

```
<?php echo $this->getRealOrderId(); ?>
```

Check this:

```
<?php
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
echo "Complete Order detail:<br>".print_r($order->debug(),true)."<br>";
?>
```

Source: http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/get-last-order-details-from-checkout-session-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

To get the order details on the checkout success page, use this

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
```

and then retrieve the customer info from the order object like this

```
//If they have no customer id, they're a guest.
if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
echo "<br/>";
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
} else {
//else, they're a normal registered user.
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
echo $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
echo "<br/>";
echo $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
}
```

Comment: As I said  http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/72091/39607 tried this already, But not working I'm getting an empty array.

Comment: $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());

I have updated answer. please try this.

Comment: Sorry didn't worked for me getLastRealOrderId() :(

Answer (score 0):

In Success.phtml

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

print_r($order->getData());

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());

if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname();
echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getEmail();
} else {
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
echo $customer->getFirstName();
}
```

Comment: Getting error : Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstname() on a non-object  and an empty array for this : print_r($order->getData());

Answer (score 0):

If you get to the success page due a redirect like

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
```

the `getOrderId()` is empty. I was facing the same problem today so I'll just add the solution to this task in case someone else is stumbling over the same issue. In your controller you'll probably have something like this. Please pay attention to the comment.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckout();

$quoteId = $reorder->getQuote()->getId(); // just an example
$orderId = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getEntityId();
$incrementId = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();


$session->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteId);
$session->setLastQuoteId($quoteId);
$session->setLastOrderId($orderId); // ***Required, otherwise getOrderId() is empty on success.phtml***
$session->setLastRealOrderId($incrementId);

$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
```